# Colorize every row in a table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already tried a couple of ways but never quite managed reaching my goal. I basically want to change the background color of every row if I use my select-All-button:

```
<th class="w70 c" id="project_table_header_checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="all" value="1" onclick="$('#project-table input[type=checkbox]').not('[disabled]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') ); colorizeRows();">
</th>
```

I also got a working way of changing the color of ONE row:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').toggleClass("bgcolor_grey", this.checked)
})
```

I thought it would be useful to just have a listener on my checkbox, that changes the row-color whenever its state changes.

How do I do this?

---

Edit:

```
 <div class="fullwidth c" id="project-table">
        <div class="box">
            <table>

            <tr>
                <th class="w70 c" id="project_table_header_checkbox">
```

Comment: Please share the markup for your table with the rows in it.

Comment: my table is generated dynamically. see edit.

Comment: Something like **[this here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/80u0ryqx/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `selectAll` to trigger `change` on the other checkboxes after you check/uncheck them

```
$('#selectAllId').change(){
    $(":checkbox").not(this).prop('checked', this.checked).change()
});
```

Now the current change event handler code you have that toggles the row classes will be triggered

Answer (score 1):

keep your change function for one checkbox and add something like this to your select all checkbox (i recommend you to use ids to form and select all checkbox)

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $('#your_form').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```